# Taking a parameter from a url and adding to links

Tags: html, jsp

I have a webpage which people are accessing and will have different url parameters

```
&group_id=xxx
```

I need to extract this parameter and add it to a link

```
<a href=${assignment.viewLink} class="btn btn-link assignment-list-link">
```

I have the following code on the page

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if(pair[0] == variable) 
            {return pair[1];}
        }
}
```

Which I can run in the console by typing:

```
getQueryVariable("group_id")
```

I am struggling writing the code to retrieve this and add it to the `href` address.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or JSP? Because the code is JavaScript, but this problem could be easily solved on the server in JSP/JSTL by just putting `${param.group_id}`.

Comment: cheers- that is a lot easier

Comment: Cool, since this seems to have answered your question, I posted it as a full answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this much easier using server side JSP/JSTL by adding `${param.group_id}` into the template. Such as:

```
<a href="${assignment.viewLink}?group_id=${param.group_id}" class="btn btn-link assignment-list-link">
```

Generally I don't recommend doing this in JavaScript (as you have been trying to) as it is much more complex and prone to bugs.